# How do I distribute my Python 3.6 application with all dependencies like in SqueezeTool

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, kivy, software-distribution

I have a python application that I built on Kivy for the GUI, and I separated that file from the RNN model. I just import that file directly with:

```
from keras_network import Network
```

I tried using the official trick to deploying using pyinstaller, but that doesn't work, as my application crashes, when running the final .exe file generated. I even made appropriate changes to the .spec file.
Isn't there an easier way to package this application in Python 3.6? (like SqueezeTool, which is too old, and isn't working in Python 3.6)

Can I compile the python files to .pyc files and have all dependencies statically linked? And why is this still such a big pain, when Python is so popular?

Comment: Why is your .exe crashing? You can try to run the .exe from the command prompt, which may produce erorrs that could help you debug the issue. If you are still having trouble, add the error output to your question as an edit.

Comment: It showed some kivy import errors. I raised an issue at their Github repo. Hopefully, they will respond to it. In the meantime, I switched to PyQt5 and I was able to get a final Package and executable by using PyInstaller out of it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok... I finally got it to work.
I came up with this solution after I implemented the whole project in PyQt5, and while trying to package it with PyInstaller.

Here is how I got it to work (for people who could have any problems later):

1. Used python 3.5
2. Install Windows 10 SDK for some missing files that should've been with MSVC 2015.
3. Install the dev version PyInstaller from:
   pip install https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/archive/develop.zip --upgrade
4. Used the command to include my data files, as well as including hidden import h5py:
   pyinstaller --add-data keras_model.h5;. --add-data TrainingData.txt;. --hidden-import=h5py --hidden-import=h5py.defs --hidden-import=h5py.utils --hidden-import=h5py.h5ac --hidden-import=h5py._proxy project-name.py
5. Then edited the .spec file generated. Added "from kivy.deps import sdl2, glew" without the quotes in the beginning of the file after the comment. Also added "*[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins)]," without the quotes in the COLLECT() function call as the 6th argument.
6. Then used the following command to rebuild using .spec file:
   pyinstaller --add-data keras_model.h5;. --add-data TrainingData.txt;. --hidden-import=h5py --hidden-import=h5py.defs --hidden-import=h5py.utils --hidden-import=h5py.h5ac --hidden-import=h5py._proxy project-name.spec
   Then the built application's executable was present in the 'dist\project-name\' directory. Double clicking the application lead to the application executing perfectly.
   Hope this helps anyone stuck in the same place.

Comment: Note that when you provide a `.spec` file as an argument to the `pyinstaller` command, none of the options that you show in your command have any effect. Have a look at [Using Spec Files](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/v3.3.1/spec-files.html#using-spec-files).

Comment: Are you distributing a tensorflow-gpu application ?